# Python: Slice a column string in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to modify a column string. I want to remove unwanted numbers in the column and save the modified value as a new column.

Here's an example in SQL:

Using `cast(substring(EMP_NM,0,CHARINDEX(' ',EMP_NM))as int)` I get the below result.

[image]

**How can I do this in python where I only get the "4253332" part of the numbers in a new column?**

```
df.['EMP_NM'] = df['EMP_NM'].str.slice(0, 9) -- This does not give the result I want as some values in the column can be defined as below:
```

009201135 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000

0006892203 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try `df['EMP_NM'] = [int(i) for i in df["EMP_NM"].str.split(" ").str[0]]`?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```py
df['EMP_NM'] = df['EMP_NM'].astype(str).str[0:7]
```

If this data field is read into **python** as an integer the leading '0's will be removed automatically. Therefore you can just index to keep only the first 7 characters.

- `.astype(str)`  is used to consider the field as a string for indexing. You can only index strings and not integers or floats.
- `.str[0:7]`  is used to index the string keeping 7 values.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
df['EMP_NM'] = df['EMP_NM'].str.replace('0','')
```

Or in case you have also something like this `009201135 0000000000 32331 0000000000 0000000000` as possible number. This means, something different from zero also in the other part of the code, this should works better:

```
df['EMP_fNM'] = df['EMP_NM'].str.split()[0][0].strip('0')
```